# What causes all iWork apps to have blank, unusable documents after a reinstall?

Tags: pages, iwork, keynote, numbers

After deleting and re-installing the apps, I can't use iWork. Specifically, the document area is always empty, no matter if I create a new document or open an existing one. This applies to Pages, Numbers and Keynotes.

I can guess there's something in the document, because the mouse pointer changes when I move it over the empty area. So it seems like a display error. What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: What do you exactly mean by empty, can you elaborate a little pls

Comment: What's your source? Mac App Store or disks?

Comment: It was from a CD.

Answer (score 1):

I had a little trouble getting iWork '09 to work correctly on Mountain Lion.

When I tried to create a new document from template chooser, it was blank, and I could not do anything.

When I tried to open an existing file, it said it "file  could not be opened".

This applied for Numbers, Pages, and Keynote.

This is how I solved it,

1. Moved the iWork Folder in Applications to Trash.
2. Removed `/Library/Application Support/iWork '09`
3. Re-Installed iWork (I had installation Media).
4. Then installed the Mountain Lion iWork updates.

Hope that works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have the font colour set to white.

Comment: Yes, the problem occurs in all three programs, using different documents etc. The documents open fine in other programs (e.g. Microsoft Word or Excel).

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem. If I open an existing or new iWork version 9.0.3 Pages document under OS X 10.7.2 only a blank document is visible. Anything entered remains invisible.

I find however that if I restart the iMac at this point, a Pages document opens properly - that is, it now becomes visible.

Answer (score -1):

Install this update: [Pages 08 3.0.3](https://support.apple.com/kb/dl808)

Comment: Can you explain why this fixes the issue? A little more context as to exactly what's happening would be nice.